# Automatic Body Re-Size

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make it so that the body width automatically resizes according to how many boxes are in the site. I'm also trying to make it so that the boxes are all aligned side by side while it scrolls horizontally. I've tried to do it here: http://flaming-prince.tumblr.com/ is there any way to do what i'm thinking using java script? or any form of html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the set width from your body tag, and add `white-space: nowrap` to `#posts`.

```
#posts {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This prevents content inside of `#posts` from wrapping to the next line, unless there is a `<br>` tag. This works in all major browsers and IE7+.

Then add this to prevent the children of `#posts` from inheriting `nowrap`:

```
.post {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: thats perfect! but is it normal for the posts not to be aligned anymore? because it all just seem to forever (text wise).

Comment: Edited my post to address that. Just add `white-space: normal` to `.post` and you're set. That way the posts don't inherit `nowrap`.